# HDFS put: no such file or directory even though the file is there

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to upload a file in HDFS with:

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -put /home/hive/warehouse/sample.csv hdfs://[ip_redacted]:9000/data
```

I can confirm that HDFS works, as I managed to create the `/data` directory just fine.

Even giving the full path to the .csv file gives the same error:

```
put: `/home/hive/warehouse/sample.csv': No such file or directory
```

Why is it giving this error?

Comment: `HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs hdfs dfs -put` worked

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the problem, too.

Because user `hdfs` has no permission to access one of the file's ancestry directories, so it gave the error `No such file or directory`.

As crystyxn commentted, using environment variable `HADOOP_USER_NAME` instead of `sudo -u hdfs` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is the csv file in your local system or in HDFS?  You can use -put command (or the -copyFromLocal command) ONLY to move a LOCAL file into the distributed file system.

Comment: Yes, I am moving a local file into HDFS

Comment: If your HDFS contains the path: /home/hive/warehouse/ and  if your local system also contains this path then the hdfs API probably won't
 know which one you mean. Try to use file:// or hdfs://. Maybe it picks the path you did not want to copy. Could be something like this: 
 
hdfs dfs -put -f file:/home/hive/warehouse/sample.csv hdfs://[ip_redacted]:9000/data